# How to initialize automatic static property inline?

Tags: c#, properties

I have a:

```
 public class Car {
        public static int ID {get;set;}
 }
```

How to initilize `ID` with a `0`?

Comment: default value for int is already zero

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You don't need to initialize it with a zero, as the compiler will do that automatically. But if you wanted to initialize to another value, you would do that with a static constructor:

```
static Car()
{
    ID = 0;
}
```

Comment: Is `public` in `public static Car(){...}` unnecessary? I ask this question because I am Java refugee.

Comment: @Yoda: it's not even allowed.

Comment: @Yoda: No, it's not even allowed. Force of habit. :-)

Answer (score 1):

The default value for a non nullable int is already 0.
So you won't have to do anything.

Answer (score 0):

If the type of variable in C# is value type then it will be initialized with default value. As you have defined property with int type, it will be initialized to 0.

Comment: Reference types are also initialized with their default value. That is, `null`. All types have a default.